Editing other's posts: adding to answers
I ran across this excellent answer to Can larger antennas damage an HT radio? and went through the following thought process:

Great points about desense in the front end.
Hrm, desense can be mitigated with a bandpass filter
I'll make a comment to that effect
Wait, our community values community edits
It doesn't change the the answer at all
But maybe it's a "substantial" addition? Does it matter?
[5 minutes of pondering the screen]
I'll look for guidance in meta.

After finding this helpful exchange, especially including the comments, I have enough confidence (arrogance?) to make the edit and leave a comment on the revision history inviting @tomnexus to revert if appropriate. But not enough confidence/arrogance to do it silently and without seeking feedback here.
Do we have an articulated principle regarding adjacent or substantial additions to existing answers, especially those that are already accepted or significantly upvoted? And if not, let's propose such!

Regarding your question, I'm not sure. Sorry.

Thanks @MikeWaters, I just updated the Q to include solicitation for principles if you care to respond; I find your feedback to be thoughtful and insightful even in those (rare) instances where we don't agree, so I hope you do!

Correction: new meta posts are not displayed until a moderator marks them as featured.

As it is now (without the [tag:Featured] tag), we have to intentionally visit meta.hamSE and look for new posts.

I might be interested in being a moderator again, for this and other reasons. If I did, I would take a more hands-off approach as our existing moderators do.

You may be ingested in:
The FAQ for (all) Stack Exchange Sites which should answer all common questions.

"Do we have an articulated principle regarding adjacent or substantial additions to existing answers, especially those that are already accepted or significantly upvoted?".

Yes, see the FAQ: "Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?".
Improvements that don't change the correctness of the answer are welcome.
Additions can expand on existing information and carefully might add a missed point, but they must not change how (up/dn) people would have voted; though after the edit the post might gain increased visibility, and subsequently receive more votes (possibly even reversals).
For the detailed ins and outs, that you didn't ask about, see: "How does editing work?".
